# Unable to integrate Github with Pycharm

Tags: github, pycharm

I have created a repository on Github. I am using Windows 7 64 bit and Pycharm Community edition. I want to integrate the Github repository with pycharm but I am getting the error

> Couldn't get the list of GitHub repositories
>   Connect to api.github.com:443 [api.github.com/192.30.252.127] failed: connect timed out

Although I am able to clone he same repository from command prompt using git clone command.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

Configure your proxy if using one:
File->Settings->System Settings->HTTP Proxy

Another thing to try is to clone the project locally then add as new project in Pycharm. Afterwards I was able to do all git operations under VCS->git including add/commit/push for my project.

Answer (score 0):

try to check whether you have given the path to Git executable correctly by testing it using test button next to it...(file>settings>version control>Git>path to Git Executable)

make sure you have given the git client path correctly..
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe