# Cannot login to Github from Pycharm settings

Tags: github, pycharm

I'm trying to login to Github from Pycharm using either Account or Token and both methods are giving me a timeout error.

I can see on my Github security page that there is a request but it isn't asking for my Two Factor Authentication as suggested in the Pycharm docs.

**Screenshot of my Pycharm:-**

[image: screenshot of my Pycharm]

**Screenshot of my Github security:-**

[image: screenshot of my Github security]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597139/unable-to-integrate-github-with-pycharm

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I'm working from home so I don't have a proxy.

Comment: In the last few moments I have just got it working using a token. Definitely didn't work earlier!

Answer (score 1):

Create an Application Token in Github, and enter in Pycharm.

In PyCharm settings > VCS > Github > change authentication to Token.